# How to remove specific <script> and <style> tag from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've got a third party API response that sends me JS and CSS and I inject it into the document head.

```
        Model.retrieve().then(res => {
            // inject to the DOM
            if(res) {
                $("head").prepend( res.css ); //res.css would be a <style>
                $("head").append( res.js ); // Would be a <script> ... </script>
                let div = document.getElementById( 'banner-outerwrap' );
                div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', res.html );
            } else {
                // No response, do the cleanup.
            }
        })
```

**Issue:**

I want to clean up / Remove (CSS and JS) if the response is empty. (I.e for use cases that's not applicable) but I'm not sure how to do it with jQuery without refreshing DOM. (I run this code in a directive.js and I can't refresh the DOM hence, I would need to clean up)

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: i think if the response is empty, based on your code, it's not going to append/prepend the css and js inside the head. so why would you need to remove them if they did not get added in the first place?

Comment: @tomjosef well that's a great question. I'm showing this on one view and I keep re-rendering the view based on certain dropdown items. (Like country etc). So I could essentially run the same code without refreshing page

Comment: wont removing the `src` property from the `<script>` tags work i mean like `$('script[src="js/scrpt.js"]').remove();`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam the issue is, I'm not getting an src... I'm getting the script itself. For example `<script> ..........</script>` as a string.

Comment: what i am tryign to understand is that you want to remove existing `<script>` tag altogather in the document if the response you received from the api contains empty `<script>` tags or you want to remove the contents from the tag ?

Comment: Let's say for the first time, i get a reponse. I inject script into DOM. After a user interaction, i call the same Model and it returns an empty response, I would like to remove the `<script>` tag altogether.

Comment: Hmm I think there is a way to do this, one more thing when you receive the reponse from the API you are getting that response as plain text and you are injecting it into the `<head>`  tag ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I get response as `{"js": "<script> Code...</script>"}`

Comment: added an answer see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Requirements

What I understood so far you are injecting some script wrapped in a `<script>` tag inside a document based on the text response you receive from the API and want to cleanup/remove afterward.

#### Problem

The problem is that there could be multiple scripts inside the `<head>` tag and you are not keeping the track of the injected script which would be more flexible and easier for you to manipulate your document.

#### Solution

For doing that I would prefer that you use the `DocumentFragment` function [**`createDocumentFragment`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment).

The trick is that before you inject the script you need to provide the `<script>` tag with some `id` or `class` so that you can select that tag later when the new response received rather than removing all tags.

I will continue from receiving the `response`, let say we have the following response

```
var response='<script>alert("hello all")<\/script>';
```

Now we have the above script tag as a text to assign it a `class` we need to transform it into a node and then append it to the `documentFragment` and assign it a new attribute `class` and then append it to the document

```
//create a document fragment
let htmlFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

//create a div element to hold the response
let tempNode = document.createElement('div');

//add response to the div
tempNode.innerHTML = response;

//append the <script> tag from the div to the fragment
htmlFragment.appendChild(tempNode.firstChild);

//select script tag from the fragment now
let scriptTag = htmlFragment.querySelector('script');

//add class to the <script> tag
scriptTag.setAttribute('class', 'removeables');

//append the tag to the document body
$(document.body).append(fragment);
```

once done you can now easily select and remove the script tag by

```
$('.removeables').remove();
```

A working example for the above is given below it injects the script tag on page load and then on the click of the button `delete` it removes the script tag you can open HTML inspector and view.

I have created a function `updateTags(response)` to which you can pass your `<script>` response and it returns you a `documentfragment` which you can append using `jquery` or `javascript`.

```js
//method to add script 
function updateTags(response) {
  let htmlFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  let tempNode = document.createElement('div');
  tempNode.innerHTML = response;
  htmlFragment.appendChild(tempNode.firstChild);
  let scriptTag = htmlFragment.querySelector('script');
  scriptTag.setAttribute('class', 'removeables');
  return htmlFragment;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var response = '<script>alert("hello")<\/script>';
  var fragment = updateTags(response);
  $(document.body).append(fragment);

  $("#delete").on('click', function() {
    $('.removeables').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
  </div>

  <button id="delete">remove</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. When i run your code, i get 500-internal server error. Can you please kindly check.

Comment: @TechnoCorner 500 is odd did you checked the server log and also do you want the script to run as soon it is injected to the head ? if not change `$(document.body).append(fragment)` to  `document.body.appendChild(fragment)` and then confirm if the error is still there

Comment: and when you say my code do you mean the above example snippet?

Comment: Oops. I was speaking about the demo snippet you've pasted. When running it I see 500 error . Not sure if it's jsfiddle issue

Comment: @TechnoCorner  give me 15 mins em outside let me check . i checked it before submitting the answer thou but let me confirm again meanwhile can you copy paste the above code into an html file and run from localhost to check

Comment: @TechnoCorner it does work correctly, no errors, what browser are you using i am using `chrome` currently. it shows the `alert ("hello")` on running the script

Comment: Thanks so much. I am able to get it working now. I saw bunch of 500's previously. I'm getting they are coming from jsfiddle. appreciate your time and thank you so much. People like you make this place lively! <3 SO!

Comment: i appreciate that @TechnoCorner thanks for the compliments do mark the answer as correct so that i can get my candies :D

Comment: Done :D ... Thanks for the time